# Multiple arduinos with serial monitor in one mac

Tags: arduino

I have two arduinos, The first one outputs data, this is the one I'm doing active development on.

The second one receives data and prints it to the Serial Monitor.

In the arduino app, I can set serial port, thus uploading code to any arduino, but as soon as I change it to arduino #1, i lose connection to serial monitor on number two.

Is there any way to upload data to ardunio #1 whilst getting serial data from arduino #2, for simpler debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to do both from within the Arduino IDE - I'd use a second program to view the serial output. Personally I'd probably choose [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), or even plain old cat.

I don't remember how serial ports appear on OSX, but on Linux it'd be something like:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

or

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600
```

There are also [GUI serial clients for OSX](http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-ser.html). Then you can select Arduino #1 in the IDE and keep the serial client pointed to Arduino #2.